# How to plot legends for all (only 4) types of value in a 2D array using matplotlib?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, legend

I have a 2-D array where each value is either of `0,1,2,3` and I am plotting it like:

```
array = two_d_array #two_d_array is a numpy 2-D array 
plt.imshow(array)
```

This gives me a plot where each pixel is represented by a color i.e. images has 4 different colors. How can I:

- plot it by customizing which value (either of `0, 1 ,2, 3`) corresponds to which value?
- plot a legend which tells which color belongs to `0`, which to `1` and so on?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35284501/plotting-legend-for-2d-numpy-array) answer is very close but it chooses which color to recognize and not which value.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: This might have a few more ideas to help you: https://gist.github.com/jakevdp/8a992f606899ac24b711

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by - "plot it by customizing which value (either of 0, 1 ,2, 3) corresponds to which value?"